# Cannot implement password filter

Tags: c++, c, security, winapi

I try to implement password filter, so I write a simple password filter.
I followed the document in the MSDN, and make sure that the functions are declared correctly.
I compile in VS 2010.

---

## .def file:

```
LIBRARY myFilt
EXPORTS
   InitializeChangeNotify
   PasswordFilter
   PasswordChangeNotify
```

## .cpp file:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ntsecapi.h>

void writeToLog(const char* szString)
{
    FILE* pFile = fopen("c:\\work\\logFile.txt", "a+");
    if (NULL == pFile)
    {
        return;
    }
    fprintf(pFile, "%s\r\n", szString);
    fclose(pFile);
    return;
}

// Default DllMain implementation
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    OutputDebugString(L"DllMain");
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
BOOLEAN __stdcall InitializeChangeNotify(void)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"InitializeChangeNotify");
    writeToLog("InitializeChangeNotify()");
    return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall PasswordFilter(
  PUNICODE_STRING AccountName,
  PUNICODE_STRING FullName,
  PUNICODE_STRING Password,
  BOOLEAN SetOperation
)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"PasswordFilter");
    return TRUE;
}

NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(
  PUNICODE_STRING UserName,
  ULONG RelativeId,
  PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword
)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"PasswordChangeNotify");
    writeToLog("PasswordChangeNotify()");
    return 0;
}
```

---

I put myFilt.dll in `%windir%\system32`, add "myFilt" to "Notification Packages" in the registry, restart the computer, change the password, and nothing happens.

I opened depends.exe and saw that the functions are correctly:

```
InitializeChangeNotify
PasswordChangeNotify
PasswordFilter
```

Where is the mistake??

Thanks.

Comment: Did you really add `myFile` to the registry key, not `myFilt`? Because that is the name of your DLL … Furthermore, didn’t you forget to call `writeToLog` in `PasswordFilter`?

Comment: You could try Process Monitor to find whether Windows tries to load your filter and what happens afterwards.

Comment: Yeah. I added myFilt, not myFile XD.. I run process monitor and see that the file scecli.dll is opened.. (this dll is written in Notification Packages(the first one))

Comment: Your code runs in the security context of lsa.  Don't expect to have unfettered access to files, definitely don't let fopen failure go unnoticed.  Also, you must create a 64-bit version of the DLL on the x64 version of Windows.

Comment: I found the problem!
I changed the runtime library from Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) and it works perfect! :)

Comment: @user1375970: Great, you could have found it using Process Monitor - it would show you failed attempts to locate the runtime files.

Comment: @user1375970 - you know you can add (and accept) your own answer, right? This still shows up as an open question.

Answer (score 1):

> I found the problem! I changed the runtime library from Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) and it works perfect! :)
>
> – user1375970 May 5 at 10:38

Answer (score 0):

Notification Packages
Specifies the dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) that are loaded or called when passwords are set or changed. To specify more than one file, list the file names one above the other by pressing ENTER between each file name.

above the other！